# How to order data randomly

Tags: mysql, random

I have the following MySQL. I want to pull the data in random order.

Could anyonet teach me how to do it please.

```
$Q = $this->db->query('SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName
               FROM products AS P
               LEFT JOIN categories C
               ON C.id = P.category_id
               WHERE C.Name = "Front bottom"
               AND p.status = "active"
               ');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Q = $this->db->query('SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName 
                   FROM products AS P
                   LEFT JOIN categories C
                   ON C.id = P.category_id
                   WHERE C.Name = "Front bottom"
                   AND p.status = "active"
                   ORDER BY RAND()
                   ');
```

you can use the [`RAND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function of MySQL to do that, to be noted that it would perform really slowly on huge dataset (~ about 10k). MySQL would pickup a random number for each row of the table which could lead to problem if the table is huge.

A safer method  would be to do a `SELECT count(*) as n FROM table`  and to pickup a random number and do a query with `LIMIT 1,n` to pickup the nth row. That would work if you need only 1, or you don't care having the result in same order.

After if you really need a complete random set better to do it on server side in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `ORDER BY RAND()`, but it's performance is miserable, especially for larger datasets (requires a random number for all matching rows).

Another way is randomly creating ids(Either in your code or using RAND() again: `WHERE id in (RAND(), RAND(), RAND(), RAND())` should work, but no guarantee). This gets problematic as soon as some IDs don't exist.

Here is an [interesting article on the topic](http://www.greggdev.com/web/articles.php?id=6).